# My MySQL query will not return any results?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My MySQL query keeps returning with no results even though I think it should, I've probably made a silly mistake. So a fix would be fantastic. Thanks

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS business_title, CONCAT(School_title, ', ', County, ', ', Town, ', ', Street_title, ', ', Postcode)
FROM `me-datab`.`business_main_location`
    INNER JOIN `business_site`
        ON `business_site`.Find_Me= `business_main_location`.Find_Me
    INNER JOIN `Personal`
        ON `Personal`.Personal_ID = `business_main_location`.Personal_ID
    INNER JOIN `address`
        ON `address`.Address_ID = `business_main_location`.Find_Me
```

Comment: hard to say why it does not return data without seeing the data. If possible post some data in http://sqlfiddle.com One thing could be possible that the data is not present in Join tables.

Comment: Since it's an inner join, there has to be matching rows in all the tables. If you want to return rows that don't have matches everywhere, you need to use `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: You have used columns from multiple tables, and performed joins. But you didn't specify your table name for a single column. Please specify table names for columns. Better use aliases.

Answer (score 2):

In all likelihood, one of your joins has no matching values.  You can use `left join` instead of `inner join` to return results:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS business_title, CONCAT(School_title, ', ', County, ', ', Town, ', ', Street_title, ', ', Postcode)
FROM `me-datab`.`business_main_location`
    LEFT JOIN `business_site`
        ON `business_site`.Find_Me= `business_main_location`.Find_Me
    LEFT JOIN `Personal`
        ON `Personal`.Personal_ID = `business_main_location`.Personal_ID
    LEFT JOIN `address`
        ON `address`.Address_ID = `business_main_location`.Find_Me;
```

One possibility is the `join` on `Address`; it looks suspicious.

However, if you really want help, try setting up a SQL Fiddle (www.sqlfiddle.com) with sample data and your query.